# In Rails, why can't I extract a specific value from a record using "where"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to extract a specific value from a record. I can do this to just exctract the title of the article:

```
x = Article.find(2)
x.title
```

But Why it gives an error when I do it like this

```
x = Article.where(:id => 2)
x.title
```

I want to use **"WHERE"** in my action because without it I could not be specific

Answer (score 2):

`where` returns an **`ActiveRecord::Relation`** the result of which is an ***array***, so using `x.title` won't work with `where`. You have to `iterate` through it and fetch the title.

```
x = Article.where(:id => 2)
x.each do | t|
t.title
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`#where` returns a relation so you can continue to add more conditions to a query.  You need to force it to be evaluated before you can look at properties of the result.  Since you're expecting only one response you can do

```
x = Article.where(:id => 2).first
x.title
```

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to note is that #find returns the actual record while #where returns an ActiveRecord::Relation which basically acts like an array. So if you're using #where to find a single record, you still need to remember to go into that "array" and grab the first record.

where queries give you a fair bit of flexibility -- they let you specify an exact value to find, a range of values to find, or several values to find. If you know what type of query you're looking for, you can almost guess the proper syntax for executing it.

**x = Article.where(:id => 2).last.title**

will give you the value of title